# How to change row matrix to column matrix of r output

Tags: r

i have output like this

```
[1]  1.5328880  0.7921354  2.4249702  1.1959438  6.0646937  1.8762401  0.7583533  0.4008204  2.6112780  0.9418852  0.7743362  1.2799742  0.9131632  2.5485733
[15]  2.1381849  1.2095969  3.7175617  3.0306370  4.1953817  3.4840283  6.2560619  2.0643638  5.3688523  3.8376050  2.7593817  2.5908134  1.2627320  2.4287058
[29]  1.1949429  1.3455868  1.3759200  5.1246881  2.8117952  2.9491735  0.3688918  1.1094072  1.0300070  1.5225797  1.0801546  0.9368711  1.2699792  1.7262416
[43]  2.5405910  1.2940386  1.9775465  3.6536474  1.7291007  0.2012389  1.0134464  1.8805344  0.6091825  2.4594666  1.4967420  0.1777788  1.6966542  1.2317400
[57]  1.4315372  1.3579202 16.5092201 10.4996198  4.4006079  2.0371990  0.4831954  5.3806799  2.2858763  2.2548254  1.1656137  2.2835499  2.0189054  4.3079575
[71]  0.3851891 24.1614092 14.1610663  4.8602176  1.2510881  2.3340540  2.3899216
```

I want to convert it to column format
[image]

Comment: use the function `t()` to transpose

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a vector

```
x <- 1:10
x
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Use `matrix` with `ncol = 1`

```
matrix(x, ncol = 1)

#      [,1]
# [1,]    1
# [2,]    2
# [3,]    3
# [4,]    4
# [5,]    5
# [6,]    6
# [7,]    7
# [8,]    8
# [9,]    9
#[10,]   10
```

Or if you want it as a dataframe

```
as.data.frame(matrix(x, ncol = 1))
```

---

You can also convert a vector to column-matrix using double transpose

```
t(t(x))
```

`t(x)` converts it into one-row matrix whereas `t(t(x))` converts it into one-column matrix.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dim` to add the dim attributes in a `vector`.  A `matrix` is a `vector` with `dim` attributes

```
 dim(x) <- c(length(x), 1)
```

---

Or use the `dim<-`

```
`dim<-`(x, c(length(x), 1))
#      [,1]
# [1,]    1
# [2,]    2
# [3,]    3
# [4,]    4
# [5,]    5
# [6,]    6
# [7,]    7
# [8,]    8
# [9,]    9
#[10,]   10
```

#### data

```
x <- 1:10
```